# How to drag and reorder UITableViewCell from one UITableView to another similar to trello app?

Tags: uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0, trello, uilongpressgesturerecogni

I want to make animations like the "trello" iOS app . In that app there are many uitableviews placed horizontally on a scrollview. Now user can long press any rows of the table and can drag it to another table. The user can also reorder rows in the selected table or in other tables as well .I have tried some solutions and logic that allow user to drag rows to another table but its not working properly . It is just in the starting stage so it have many bugs.
   If you can provide me some samples that can help me to my goal or some ways which i should do to make this features than that would be much appreciated .

Thanks.